# Customizing spotify backstage UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, backstage

I am designing a UI for a developer portal based on spotify backstage. So far i have added google OAuth to the application. Now i want to change the login ui based on a predefined figma. I tried to read through the documentaion for backstage but I must confess I am new to typescript (in which backstage is written.) so the code is already pretty hard to understand for me and the documentation also doesn't really deal with the issue of how to create custom UI.

The closest i found was how to change the theme of the project like dark theme etc. I was wondering if there is a way to radically change the ui of the application.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question [has something to do with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73070882/backstage-how-to-modify-the-docs-theme-and-colors-mkdocs) the one I answered.

In addition, you can change the entire interface using `@material-ui/core` itself and create your components in React.

Comment: Hi, paulo. thanks for the reply. This isn't really relevant for me right now as i asked this question months ago. But if somebody else finds your answer useful i will accept this answer. Thanks