# Backstage: How to modify the docs theme and colors (MKDocs)

Tags: themes, mkdocs, backstage

I want to change the techdocs theme and its colors on a global level in a Backstage app (not in each Docs folder). How can I achieve this?

Example: Change the background color for all code snippets.

Comment: Looks similar to this: https://github.com/backstage/backstage/discussions/5711

Answer (score 0):

Backstage allows you to customize the entire application. There is even a [section dedicated](https://backstage.io/docs/getting-started/app-custom-theme#creating-a-custom-theme) to this topic that I was able to contribute to.

Below is a simple example of a custom color palette:

```
import { BackstageOverrides } from '@backstage/core-components';
import {
  BackstagePaletteOptions,
  createTheme,
  genPageTheme,
  darkTheme,
  BackstageTheme,
  SimpleThemeOptions,
  shapes,
} from '@backstage/theme';

/**
 * Create a custom color palette
 */
const customPalleteColors: BackstagePaletteOptions = {
  ...darkTheme.palette,
  primary: {
    main: '#d97800',
  },
  secondary: {
    main: '#004ABE',
  },
  navigation: {
    // Sidebar
    background: '#000',
    indicator: '#F58220',
    color: '#fff',
    selectedColor: '#fff',
    navItem: {
      hoverBackground: '#4d4d4d',
    },
  },
};

/**
 * Sets the theme options object
 */
const customThemeOptions: SimpleThemeOptions = {
  palette: customPalleteColors,
  defaultPageTheme: 'home',
  /* Headers pages */
  pageTheme: {
    home: genPageTheme({colors: ['#FFFFFF', '#FFF'], shape: shapes.wave}),
  },
};

/**
 * Create a custom theme using the defined options
 */
const myCustomTheme: BackstageTheme = createTheme(customThemeOptions);

/**
 * An override forces a style value to be subscripted when we are not using it.
 * tokens provided by the theme or for global UI elements that are native to Backstage
 *
 * @param theme BackstageTheme
 * @returns BackstageOverrides
 */
const customThemeOverrides = (theme: BackstageTheme): BackstageOverrides => {
  return {
    // Overrides for all headers
    BackstageHeader: {
      header: {
        width: 'auto',
        background: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',
        borderBottom: '1px solid #E7EBF0',
        boxShadow: 'none',
      },
      title: {
        color: '#000',
        fontSize: 24,
      },
      subtitle: {
        color: `${theme.palette.grey}`,
      },
    },
  };
};

/**
 * The final generated theme object
 * with custom colors and global overrides
 */
export const customTheme: BackstageTheme = {
  ...myCustomTheme,
  overrides: {
    ...myCustomTheme.overrides,
    ...customThemeOverrides(myCustomTheme),
  },
};
```

Comment: Is there any way to toggle between light mode and dark mode?

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi Yes. You can create multiple themes, including.